# Is there a tool that helps with Modern UI column formatting?

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, modern-experience, modern

It seems like the new column [formatting JSON-based solution](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#get-started-with-column-formatting) is much more inferior in comparison to the old client-side rendering with JSLink. I am mostly talking about dev experience.

For example, for the last few years, I've been using an amazing [Cisar Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cisar/nifbdojdggkboiifaklkamfpjcmgafpo?hl=en) (credits to AndrewMarkeev) that allows us to write and preview the results live, as we type.

Is there some tool you know of that allows us to write these ugly JSON-based "formulas" for the modern UI?

Comment: and only now I realised you asked about column formatting, not site scripts :)
my bad :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used it yet but Chris Kent's ColumnFormatter client side webpart might be what you're looking for.

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-solutions/tree/master/solutions/ColumnFormatter

Answer (score 2):

The one which became trending recently is [SharePoint Site Designer](https://www.sitedesigner.io)

However, you should compare it to the latest schema from Microsoft, because MS constantly adds new features and Site Designer might have some delay in support for new elements.

**UPD**
It doesn't answer the question directly, but it's just another tool for convenient JSON manipulation with [SharePoint Site Scripts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-overview). I misread the question :)

Comment: I gave you a plus one just because that tool is amazing and really makes site scripts more accessible (not that they weren't before).